# Catholic Lay Saints Who were Economically Well Off When They Died

Tags: catholicism, saint, communion-of-saints, veneration, laity

So says Matt. 19:24---

> It is easier for a camel to pass through the eye of a needle, than for a rich man to enter into the kingdom of heaven.

QUESTION: I would like to know who (if any) among the **non-royal laity** have been canonized by the Catholic Church who died a natural death (i.e., not martyred) as a lay person in an economic state that might be considered well-to-do or better? (I am interested in canonized Saints who fit this criteria; nevertheless, if anyone is aware of a well-to-do individual whose cause for Sainthood has been opened, I would like to know of that individual(s) as well.)

*Remark:* I have not been able to think of one such individual. I know that the Ven. Leo Dupont was born wealthy and did many wonderful things with his money, much of which he spent on charitable and pious endeavors. I don't believe that he died poor. However, he still has not been declared a Saint in the Catholic Church.

Comment: +1 For a very well scoped question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- St. Sabina was a rich Roman martyr whose house on the Aventine Hill was donated to the Church.
- St. Paula was noble Roman widow who funded St. Jerome's translation of the Vulgate.
- Ven. Pauline Jaricot (and probably some others mentioned in Neill, [*They Lived the Faith: Great Lay Leaders of Modern Times*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=8055)) was left a rich inheritance.
- [Bl. Bartolo Longo](https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/our-lady-of-pompeii-5310) was a master fundraiser who donated his property to Our Lady of Pompeii, the church he helped build.

The wealthy are to give alms.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I exclude those who died poor, such as Pauline Jaricot, or those who gave away all their money. I would like to know of any lay, non-royal, individuals who remained reasonably well of at death and became a canonized Saint; as I said before, I can't think of one.

Comment: Two interesting things about Bl. Pauline Jaricot (1) Bishop Georges Colomb referred to Pauline Jaricot as: a model "for many Christians who want to live their Faith as baptized people without entering religious life."  (2) And St. John Vianney says to her: "Through the hands of the Blessed Virgin, the Good God frequently grants one of the greatest gifts---an understanding of the way of the Cross."

Comment: @I.Chekhov Yes, she was a close friend of the Curé of Ars.

Comment: @I.Chekhov Well, such covetousness would seem to be contrary to sanctity.

Comment: Covetousness, yes; but I am trying to find any individuals who were wealthy, remained well off, and used their wealth and state of life for the glory of God. Ven Dupont seems obviously to be one. I am searching for more.

Comment: **Catholic Lay Saints Who were Economically Well Off When They Died?** Blessed Pauline Jaricot  died in poverty!!!

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

[St. Marie-Azélie Guérin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Martin_and_Marie-Az%C3%A9lie_Gu%C3%A9rin) died a [well-off business woman](https://www.tektonministries.org/this-couple-coined-the-term-vocation-awareness/):

> Louis was a watchmaker and Zelie a lace-maker who employed 15 women or more at a time, allowing them to work from their homes. Zelie’s lace-making business became so successful that Louis sold his watchmaking business, helping Zelie manage her business.  The revenue from their business allowed Louis to retire and raise their daughters after Zelie died of breast cancer when St. Therese was only four years old.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.